# Python3 how to define one length byte-string?(Solved)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been search all the resource from internet about this question, but there's no answer can be use. Here is the Error code below i'm testing:

TypeError: ljust() argument 2 must be a byte string of length 1, not str

The code i'm using:

```
s = 'test'

s.ljust(6, '\0') or s.ljust(6, '^')

#BOTH are not work

#if i try with

s.ljust(6, b'\0') 
#or 
s.ljust(6, b'^')

#Will get

#TypeError: The fill character must be a unicode character, not bytes

#Please help!! Thank you so much!

    def _str2long(s, w):
        n = len(s)
        m = (4 - (n & 3) & 3) + n
        sb = bytes(s)
        print('====')
        print(sb)
        print(type(sb))
        print(type(_XXTEA_FILL_CHAR))
        s = sb.ljust(m, _XXTEA_FILL_CHAR)
        v = list(struct.unpack('<%iL' % (m >> 2), s))
        if w: v.append(n)
        return v
```

Then the output i get

Output

```
> ==== b't\xf5\xf3)6\x8f\x13##|\xabTd\xf8\xcd\xb9\x88!\x16O~Q\x0c\xed\xee\xc1\xa3\xd15\xda\x0b6\xd0\xdb\xff\xbb\x15\xbe\n\x98\x16\xb7VsI\xbc\xb5\x0e\xed\xc1\xda\x8aii\x0e]V\xe0\x08z\n\xe4\xe9J\x15\x00\xc64\xe0\xfc<\xba:\xe5:\x9d\xffo.\x92\xb9\x7f\x1c\xecm\xcd\xc5\x8f\xb1/\x86/\x954^\xb1\x81<\xe1:fJl!\x1b\x16\xdf\x7f\x818.my#\xc1\xf2"i\xf0\x96\xed\xea\x00F\x1e!\xa9\xbb\xe24fT[\x80yC\x11Q\xd0
> \xfd\x8b=Is\x14J\xfe\xae\n\x0cMvv7\tz<\xa44S\xb6\x17&\xae\x8f\xa3TJ"J\x9c\x82\x1cY\xe6\xd3\xb2\xb2\xc5Y\xd5\xe9\xff\xa7\xaa\x17K\xed\xdf\x1d\xba\xc76B\x0fr\x066\x0e2.\xce\xda:ML\'\xcd2@\x1e\xb1\x06\t1\x1d9\xf3\x92\xa0@H\xeaZ\xa6\xf8]\x08\x8dA~*\xa0wdO\x881\x93I\xa5\x88\n\x08#\x9f\xe3\x88\xe9+\x04\xd5\xde\x02\xceF\xc1\x0e\x92\x1a\xc4*\x97KMC\'\xd3\xab\xd3\x1c\xe5\x1c\x1b\xb1\xb7\xcf\x95\x8c\xbe\xbd\t\xae\xfdOy\x14\\\x86\x18b\xdc\x97`\xed\xf5\xc7\\\xb4\n\xf2\xb2\xb3~\xc7\x870\xc2\x81\xf71\n\xf2q\x13\xd8\x049\xc1\xd9j\xb0\xcc\x15\xd2i\xb9\x9f\xfe\xa1x\xb5V\x11H\xf5\xd5\xbf]\x9e\xfb\xdd\x11\x8fl\xf3\xe7\xb8]\xd6\xb5*\x86\xd2\xb0\xfb\xebQ\x93\xc8\x05\x1d\xbe8t\x08\xbeK2\xd3\x13Za\x85X\xb7\xb4\xd26\x0cT6\\\xa9e\x80\xd7\x89\xdc\x1b\x8c\x94\xd1j1\n9\x02;d\nd\x1d,\x1f\x18{\xec/|\x18\xeb\xe4\x96\xcbI\xb75\x7f$H=lAu0\x81\xf95\x8b\x18\xfb|\x0c\x97\xf1n\xe5\xe4\x87\x91\x13\xa1\xf5\xb2\xa8\x11\xee\xa5z]\x80\x04&\xd6^,\x96a[F\xef\xefc\n\x03\xc1\x93\x0c7c\xba\xca\xc8\xf0\xf2\xe8_s\xb3\x8e5\xe6\xa9m=\xfdN\x9eG\xdf\xbdR\xdb\x8d1\xf8]n\xa6Rn(\xdbR&$\x06\xe3\xbfW\xeb,\xcf\x17\xe4<\xafh\x07\xe4m\x82\x7f\'\xc7\x83\x82\x9b\xda\xed\xc3U\x08\xc5\xa2}\xff\xa3.\x07\xcb\x80\xc0H\xb9\xf7rZ\x0f\xaeD\x1f\xaf*\xb2VGrO\xfc\x11\xce\x946%\x8d\xd4sI\x06\xbc\xdf\x8aoWy`\x8a{\x00\x9d\xdf\x07\x00\xbf\x02\xc4d\x89c\xb1\x9agW\xff\xa9\xab4\xdd5\x13{\xa9G\xebs_u\xc7\x00|\xad\xc8\xb6\xad|\xf8QcT\xf7\xd0t\xf1\xbf\xc6\x81\x80\x97\x06\xc6\xe9+|W\xa1a
> \x1f\xfb\xcc\xc7Y2\x8c\xac\xd6(V?\xda\xb0\x89\xa7\xc0(\xec;\xa2V9D\xf9\xa3<\xd3+\xba\xc6\xb4\x8b\x17\x12\x8e\xa8.\xa4~\xeb\xe6Q\xc2\x92\xcb\x9e\xd1A\xb0\x9fS\xca<\xd4zY?n\x12\xecH\xaf\x997\nT\x9a\x1d\xee\xbb\x9a\xb5\xfe
> \x9ev@\x08\xa8\xaa\x82hc\x98u\xd8\x7f\x80\xfd\x0e_\xfd\x8f\x9f\xf5^\x958<z\xea\x11Ft3\x95\x8e\x8f]\xd9\xe83\xd4\x04\xd6f\x8d\x06Fh\xc6\x7f\xb6B\x13K\x88S\x9d\xae\xbb\xf0\xaaTS\xe2\x1a^e\'"\xc0\x89\xdd%\x83+"0g\xae=\xcf\xa7zg\xc8b\x1c^\xd2\x81mb\x0c)\xca\x94\xcc\xa7\x95\xba\xe4\xde\x1fZ\xa3\x04\xfa\x16\x8c\xb3\xfe\xb5e?
> A\x99f/R&\x81\xbaH\xf7\x18\x08V$\x82\xfa\x86t|\xb3\x00\xf2\xcb/\x92Z(\x11\xf5\x13\x15\x00\x0f\x9dY\x08\x02\r5mya\x1f\xdf'
> <class 'bytes'> 
> <class 'bytes'> 
>  Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File "C:\Users\LilPoppy\Downloads\cocos2dx-lite-2d\crypt.py", line
> 162, in <module>
>     main()   File "C:\Users\LilPoppy\Downloads\cocos2dx-lite-2d\crypt.py", line 160, in
> main
>     decrypt(*prepare())   File "C:\Users\LilPoppy\Downloads\cocos2dx-lite-2d\crypt.py", line 143, in
> decrypt
>     decrypt_file(f, key, sign)   File "C:\Users\LilPoppy\Downloads\cocos2dx-lite-2d\crypt.py", line 103, in
> decrypt_file
>     decoded = xxtea_decrypt(data[len(sign):], key)   File "C:\Users\LilPoppy\Downloads\cocos2dx-lite-2d\crypt.py", line 69, in
> xxtea_decrypt
>     k = _str2long(key.ljust(16, _XXTEA_FILL_CHAR), False) TypeError: The fill character must be a unicode character, not bytes
```

NVM, maybe the content i'm try to do is something sensitive to ljust func...
Here is my solution

```
def left_ajust(s, n, b):
    result = bytearray(s) if type(s) is bytes else bytearray(s, 'utf-8')
    if len(s) < n:
        v = bytearray([])
        for i in range(n - len(s)):
          v[0:0] = b;
        result[len(s):0] = v
    return bytes(result)
```

Comment: Your code works fine as written. Guess it's really `s = b'test'`, not `s = 'test'`? That `b` prefix is important (and adding it to either `str` literal in `ljust` would make them `bytes` literals to make types agree when `s` is actually `bytes`).

Answer (score -1):

Just like any other byte string: `b'\0'` and `b'^'`.

Example:

```
>>> # Using strings
>>> s = 'test'
>>> s.ljust(6, '^')
'test^^'
>>>
>>> # Using bytes
>>> s = b'test' # note the `b` prefix
>>> s.ljust(6, b'^') # need `b` prefix
b'test^^'
```

Comment: umm...thank you but i just got TypeError: The fill character must be a unicode character, not bytes

Comment: @HotFlow, `b'test'.ljust(6, b'^')` returns `b'test^^'`, as expected. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Here is the source code i'm cloneing from https://github.com/c0i/cocos2dx-lite/blob/7383a26230f56f501bfabeda12db9c3b37c8d5d8/crypt.py#L34

Comment: The first code in OP actually [works fine](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v1jBVkG9JLW4RJ2Lq6AoM69Eo1gvJ6u0uETDTEdBPcZAXVMTi3gcUPj/fwA "Python 3 – Try It Online"). If you meant to write `s = b'test'`, then you should be using the `b` prefix for the fill character too